# Storing and Fetching more than one table from a Single Model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, model

Here is my Model

```
<?php
class VehicleModel extends Eloquent 
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'AutoID';  # to change the primary key else laravel will consider id as primary key
    protected $table = 'vehicle';
}
```

Using this i can fetch

```
$vehiclelist = VehicleModel ::all();
```

But i need to fetch another table from the same model

Is it possibel to have something like this

```
<?php
class VehicleModel extends Eloquent 
{
 protected $primaryKey = 'AutoID';  # to change the primary key else laravel will consider id as primary key
 protected $table = 'vehicle';
 protected $secondtable = 'route';
}
```

And should be accessible by

```
$routelist= Detail::make(VehicleModel ::$secondtable );// This is the thing i am doing wrong
```

Is it possible in this way if not how can i do this so that i should be able to fetch the details from same model .

Note : 
I can't create seperate model for each table because i need to fetch many (different) tables for each form

Comment: `vehicle` and `route` sound an awful lot like a relation to me. In this case you will be best off creating a model. I mean it isn't that much work, you basically just have to add another class. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes i should create another model , but extending another class is not the better idea right ?

Comment: I don't think so. `vehicle` and `route` don't have any shared functionality do they?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, Yes they don't have any shared functionality. Yes now i understand

Comment: Alright. I'm gonna write an answer anyways ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67529/discussion-between-chennai-and-lukasgeiter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple tables that are *different things* (not multitable inheritance) you really should create a model for each table. It isn't that much work but will make things a lot easier.

For the following example, let's assume that one vehicle can have many routes. And in the database you `VehicleID` in the `route` table referencing `AutoID` in the `vehicle` table.

Then you can add these two relations inside your models

#### VehicleModel

```
public function routes(){
    return $this->hasMany('RouteModel', 'VehicleID');
}
```

#### RouteModel

```
public function vehicle(){
    return $this->belongsTo('VehicleModel', 'VehicleID');
}
```

Now here are some examples how to use it:

```
$vehicle = VehicleModel::find(1);
$routesOfVehicle1 = $vehicle->routes;

$route = RouteModel::find(1);
$vehicleOfRoute1 = $route->vehicle;

$allVehiclesIncludingTheirRoutes = VehicleModel::with('routes')->get();
```

For more information, read the [Laravel Docs on Relations](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you extend VehicleModel class?
I think there is no way except extend.

```
<?php
class VehicleModel extends Eloquent 
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'AutoID';  # to change the primary key else laravel will consider id as primary key
    protected $table = 'vehicle';
}

class RouteModel extends VehicleModel
{
    protected $table = 'route';
}

class StuffModel extends VehicleModel
{
    protected $table = 'stuff';
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, But i need to check if i extend the class will i able to get the details like **$table**